# Creating 2 views in view using programatically contraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to add 2 views to a `CallOutView`. The `pushButton` should be at the bottom with a static height of 20. The `topView` should then fill the rest. I've tried to do this programmatically using [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io/docs/). However it seems like the pushbutton just fills everything? what am i doing wrong?

```
       callOutView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(-70+(self.frame.width/2), -65, 140, 60))
        callOutView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        callOutView?.clipsToBounds = true
        callOutView?.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.addSubview(callOutView!)

        let topView = UIView()
        topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)
        callOutView?.addSubview(topView)


        let pushButton = UIButton()
        pushButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#09316e").colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)
        pushButton.setTitle("Se Mere", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        pushButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        pushButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(8)
        callOutView?.addSubview(pushButton)

        topView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(callOutView!).offset(0)
            make.left.equalTo(callOutView!).offset(0)
            make.bottom.equalTo(pushButton).offset(0)
            make.right.equalTo(callOutView!).offset(0)
            make.height.equalTo(40)

        }

        pushButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.height.equalTo(20)
            make.top.equalTo(topView).offset(0)
            make.left.equalTo(callOutView!).offset(0)
            make.bottom.equalTo(0).offset(0)
            make.right.equalTo(callOutView!).offset(0)

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are some constraints conflicting with each other, which will make the autolayout system break some of them.

```
topView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    ...
    make.bottom.equalTo(pushButton).offset(0)
    ...
}


pushButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    ...
    make.top.equalTo(topView).offset(0)
    ...
}
```

The two constraints above tell the autolayout system:

1. Place `topView` and `pushButton` with top edge aligned.
2. Place `topView` and `pushButton` with bottom edge aligned.

Which is impossible if you give `topView` and `pushButton` different heights.

Also, this is not what you want obviously. What you want is **"place `pushButton` right below the `topView`"**.

Here's the modified code to make `pushButton` being placed right below the `topView`:

```
topView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    ...
    make.bottom.equalTo(pushButton.snp_top).offset(0)
    ...
}


pushButton.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    ...
    make.top.equalTo(topView.snp_bottom).offset(0)
    ...
}
```